# ASUS X302UV compatibility with Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, touchpad, asus

I'm about to purchase a new laptop and [Asus X302U](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X302UV/specifications/)-R4023D seems to be the best option for me. Mine will be:

- i5 6200U
- 1TB HDD 5400
- GeForce® 920MX with 2GB DDR3
- 13.3" 16:9 Full HD (1920x1080)
- DDR3L 1600(O.C.) MHz SDRAM - 8 GB

I need a laptop for hard browsing, business tasks (using messengers heavily), media entertainment (watching HD movies offline and online).

I'm going to test Artful Aardvark on this model with my USB flash at the local shop. However, it's scheduled on Saturday. Before this I'd like to have your advice. Maybe, someone used this laptop with Ubuntu. Did you have any issues?

I've checked the model's nVidia video-card - it does have drivers for Ubuntu. I also searched askubuntu and saw there are touchpad issues with other Asus X-series laptops. Anything like that in X302U?